# How do I reference the name of the current class in Sphinx?

Tags: python, documentation, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

Say that I have a class structure as follows:

```py
class A:
  def print(self, x):
     r"""Prints x.

     Example::

        >>> a = A()
        >>> A.print(3)
     """
     print(x)

class B(A): pass
```

When printing the documentation for `B.print`, the example would stated with the parent class `A`, which is annoying.

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to reference the name of the current class when writing the documentation in Sphinx?

   If not, assume that the documentation in `A.print` is quite large, so copying the whole documentation just to change the name of the class would be quite annoying. Then,
2. What would be the best way to implement the behaviour above?

Comment: Do you really have backticks as docstring delimiters?

Comment: What is the actual output?

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. It seems like the actual question is "How do I modify the docstring for a method that is inherited from a base class?".

Comment: On the backticks, no, sorry, I just wrote that on a plain document as an example and did not think too much about it :D  I'll edit it now.
On the question, well, that question that you ask is more general, and it would require effort from my side. I would like to know whether it is possible to have access to a variable of the form `{current_class_name}`, that would be then resolved by Sphinx during the compilation of the documentation. That being impossible, yeah, I would take any more general solution to this problem

Comment: "Effort from my side" = Manually modifying the docstrings in each of the subclasses, rather than having the docstrings correctly generated without any intervention from my part.